# Video of html5 doesn't run

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html, html5-video

I have a video Element of html5. i have implemented it as

```
  </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
    <video id="ss" runat="server"  controls="controls" tabindex="5"   class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup="{}" poster="my_video_poster.png">
      <source src="Videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
     </div>

     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="View" onclick="Button1_Click" />


    </form>
</body>
```

at `cs` file

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ss.Attributes.Add("src", "~/Videos/1.mp4");

    }
```

I want to change the Src of html5 at the click of a button. but this particular method doesn't able to run. thanks for any assistance.

Comment: make the fiddle on  http://jsfiddle.net that would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is not translate the path, is did not even know that this is a path, so the symbol `~` is not translated to url path.

`ss.Attributes.Add("src", "~/Videos/1.mp4");`

Second bug, the attribute you try to set is not on the source.

`<source src="Videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">`

So correct the path, and the place of the attribute and is probably work.

Comment: Sir so how shall i set a src at a button click. i have google many sites but couldn't reached to a solution.

Comment: @Abhishekgupta Set runat=server on `<source src="Videos/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">` with an id, and change that one.

Comment: Thanks sir it works now. I have been working on this for last 6 days. finally it works.